# Payment method differences by subdomain

Tags: commerce, rules, domain-access, subsites

I am trying a configuration where I have drupal commerce setup in different subdomains representing different stores using domain access and domain access entity.

My issues is that when i enable paypal wps rule as payment method, the same information that I have for receiver in one subdomain is copied over to all subdomains. Is it possible to have a unique payment method details by each subdomain? So products purchased from one subdomain are processeed by its own unique payment method details?  Can rules be used to identify which domain the order is from and process it for payment details for that domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [Domain Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_rules) module provides a condition so that you could limit a configuration by a domain.

Comment: Domain Rules does provide a module to check what domain the cart belongs to and then using Conditional Rules module I was able to create conditions to apply a different payment action based on the domain the cart belonged to.  your suggestion did the trick.  I am not sure how roboust this solution is as I have not tested it thoroughly but I wanted to accept your answer on this quickly, as it did help me and answered the question.